# How can i join a group of matrices? MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I need to join a group of matrices and store this union in other one. 
I think that it can be possible with a for loop but i have a lot of data in the matrices and that could involve many calculations.
How can I do this? 
[image]

Thank you very much

Comment: .. `[N1;N2;N3]`?

Comment: That `N1+N2+N3` does mathematically make no sense. Seeing your matrices are not the same size that is an invalid operation. Judging your picture what @Divakar said gives you the solution.

Comment: @Divakar thank you very much,it is very simple and i was thinking in loops hahah

Answer (score 0):

result = union(union(N1,N2),N3) (as sets)

result = [N1;N2;N3] (as vectors or matrices)

[union (matlab doc)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/union.html)